# insert test data into TDengine server but it return [0x15] err

Tags: go, tdengine

I wrote a piece of go code to connect TDengine server from Windows as below:

```
var taosuri = "root:taosdata/tcp(10.233.65.65:6030)/"
s, err := sql.Open("taosSql", taosuri)

if err != nil {
fmt.Errorf("failed to connect TDengine, err:%v", err)
return nil, nil, err
}
fmt.Println(s.Ping())
fmt.Println(s.Exec(`insert into test.tb1 values(now+1s, 2)`))
```

But I got an error 0x15.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find 0x15 means "Unable to resolve FQDN" from the source code src/inc/taoserror.h.

```
#define TSDB_CODE_RPC_FQDN_ERROR                TAOS_DEF_ERROR_CODE(0, 0x0015)  //"Unable to resolve FQDN"
```